# getting runtime exception when using cursor in this code

Tags: android, listview, cursor

my onitemclick part of code is .....

i have three column id title and notetext in which i just want to display text from my sqlite database column (notetext) when i click title from listview.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
    {
Cursor cursor = (Cursor)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2); // i m getting error here

String product = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("notetext"));

Intent myintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),view1.class);

myintent.putExtra("product", product);

startActivity(myintent);

   }
});
```

Comment: 01-04 05:10:32.675: I/Process(1250): Sending signal. PID: 1250 SIG: 9
01-04 05:10:43.545: D/dalvikvm(1323): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 56K, 7% free 2672K/2848K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
01-04 05:10:43.865: D/gralloc_goldfish(1323): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-04 05:10:45.215: D/dalvikvm(1323): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 12K, 4% free 3165K/3296K, paused 34ms, total 37ms
01-04 05:10:45.266: D/dalvikvm(1323): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 3220K/3352K, paused 33ms, total 34ms
01-04 05:10:45.275: I/dalvikvm-heap(1323): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.863MB for 635812-byte allocation

Comment: The stacktrace of your Exception, not some random garbage collection stuff.

Comment: but how to get stacktrace ??

Comment: logCat<http://www.google.com/search?q=logcat+in+eclipse&oq=logcat+in+eclipse&aqs=chrome..69i57.7388j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8>

Comment: actually this is log cat stuff ...

Comment: Ok you must post the part of logcat that is red(mean:error).And please post it on your question. not comment it.

Comment: hey MM-BB could you please add me on gmail so i share my code with you i am not able to complete my app from last 1 month :( please have a look on my code :)

Comment: hey @Niek i m getting this exception 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.database.Cursor

Comment: Apparently, `arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);` returns a `String` object and not a `Cursor`.

Comment: now i am using this code instead of previous one 

String product = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notetext)).getText().toString();

and it gave me nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
  cursor.moveToPosition(position);
  String product = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("notetext"));
```

Comment: actually the line Cursor cursor = (Cursor)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2); give exception

Comment: please help me and review my code so hopefully you understand the exception bcoz i am new in android developing and it seems very difficult in beginning

Comment: exception is a statement in logcat that is red.

Comment: 01-04 05:10:56.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1323): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 05:10:56.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1323): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.database.Cursor
01-04 05:10:56.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at com.ramanrayat.notelet.menu$1.onItemClick(menu.java:104)
01-04 05:10:56.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)

Comment: thanks man your code is working ...that time i just not put it on right way but now i understand we need to put cursor to the specific position before fetching column from table  :)) thanks a lot ..